# ASP.NET OAuth Microsoft Single Tenant login

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, owin

I creating an Intranet portal and want to create a login using the company's Azure AD accounts. I setup an Azure App Authentication and set it to single tenant, and downloaded the sample project from Azure.

My problem is that it's not enforcing single tenant and allowing Microsoft accounts from other organizations.

Here's my configuration code in Startup.cs

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {

                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow personal and work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
                // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name
                // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter 
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true
                },

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

In Azure, support account types is set to single tenant
[image: Azure Single Tenant setting]

What am I missing to enforce logins from a single organization?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to specify which tenants are allowed.
Try adding the following to your `TokenValidationParameters`

```
ValidIssuers = new List<string>()
{
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your-tenant-id>"
}
```

Comment: I had tried that, and tried it again, but it doesn't change the behavior.